# Word or phrase for all changes to an employee’s role/position/level?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is a suitable word or phrase describing *all* changes to an employee’s role/position/designation/level in a company? These changes would include promotions/demotions (e.g. “Staff” to “Executive”), re-designations (e.g. “Programmer” to “Network Administrator”), and even transfers (to different departments or branches/stores).

I was thinking along the lines of “**employees' role changes**”, but believe it to be unsuitable as not all changes will cause the employee’s role to change. For example, one may hold the designation of “Accountant” and belong to “Staff” level. He is then promoted/upgraded to the level of “Senior Staff”, but is still an accountant and his job scope remains the same. Thus, his role is effectively unchanged even though he has been "promoted".

Single words or short phrases describing these changes would be appreciated.

Comment: The Anglo-Saxons weren't big into corporate management and didn't invent any short words for this kind of thing.  It is to be your company's jargon, so make a term up for the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a system that does this.  We call them either "**employee status modifications**" which was shortened to "employee status mods" right away and now we just say "employee mod(s)".

You might want to make sure that all people in your system will always be employees and if not, switch employee to user.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a phrase like **employment events**.  This would cover a range of staus, roll, and even temporary attendance events, such as a leave.  If you needed a shorter title, you could use **job events**.

Since this is data that is specific to an individual employee, you don't need the word *employee*, just as you don't need to say ***employee*** name.

Comment: Thanks! :) **Events** is a little too general for our use, since we have seperate windows/systems to deal with leaves and all other events like increments and resignations. But I appreciate the suggestions nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Different assignments of roles, positions or jobs, may describe the changes you are referring to in your question.